# Storing state from options drop down in order to pass it to Parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to store my `searchValue` parameter based off the value that was chosen from `options`, so that I can send that value from my Child component to my Parent component. However, `searchValue` returns back as undefined. How can I store my `searchValue` based off the value that was selected in `option`?

---

I have the following:

```
class SearchField extends Component {
    state = {
        options: ["Choose search method", "Id Number", "Phone Number", "Mobile Number"]
    };

    handleSearchChoice = (e) => {
        var searchValue = e.target;
        console.log(searchValue);
    };

    render() {
       const initialValues = {
          name: ""
       };
       return (
          <Form handleSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} initialValues={initialValues}>
          {({ values, handleChange }) => (
             <React.Fragment>
                <FormGroup>
                <DateInput />
                <FormText>Enter customer info</FormText>
                <Input placeholder="mobile, id number, etc..."
                 name="name"
                 value={values.name}
                 onChange={handleChange}/>
                <FormText>Select an option</FormText>
                <Select onChange={this.handleSearchChoice}>
                  {this.state.options.map(option => (
                     <option key={option} value={option}>
                       {option}
                     </option>
                  ))}
               </Select>
               <div>
                  <Button onClick={this.isButtonEnabled}>Submit</Button>
               </div>
            </FormGroup>
         </React.Fragment>
       )}
     </Form>
   );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you're (incorrectly) trying to grab an element from the state (for some reason) when you should be grabbing the value of the selected option.

You should add a value attribute to each option

```
<option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
```

which you can then pick up in the handle method

```
handleSearchChoice = (e) => {
  var { value: searchValue } = e.target;
  console.log(searchValue);
};
```

> Note: I relabeled the [destructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `value` property to `searchValue` per your question.

You might want to rethink how you build that select element as you will receive "Choose search method" as the value of the returned default option.

Comment: I have updated my code to include your suggestion but I still get undefined. I have updated my question to include the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to set the state in the constructor.

```js
class SearchField extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      options: ["Choose search method", "Id Number", "Phone Number", "Mobile Number"]
    };
  }
  
  handleSearchChoice = (e) => {
    var searchValue = event.target.value // Refer to component API to get the selected value;
    console.log(searchValue);
  };

  render() {
    return ( 
    <Form >
      <Select onChange = {this.handleSearchChoice}>
      {this.state.options.map((option, key) => ( 
        <option key = {key}>{option}</option>
        ))}
        <Select>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```